# How to make R2 score in nn.LSTM pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I tried to make loss function with R2in nn.LSTM but i couldnt find any documentation about it . I already use RMSE and MAE loss from pytorch.

My data is a time series and im doing time series forecasting

This is the code where i use the loss function of RMSE in data training

```
model = LSTM_model(input_size=1, output_size=1, hidden_size=512, num_layers=2, dropout=0).to(device)
criterion = nn.MSELoss(reduction="sum")
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
callback = Callback(model, early_stop_patience=10 ,outdir="model/lstm", plot_every=20,)


from tqdm.auto import tqdm

def loop_fn(mode, dataset, dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer,device):
    if mode =="train":
        model.train()
    elif mode =="test":
        model.eval()
    cost = 0
    for feature, target in tqdm(dataloader, desc=mode.title()):
        feature, target = feature.to(device), target.to(device)
        output , hidden = model(feature,None)
        loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(output,target))
        
        if mode =="train":
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        cost += loss.item() * feature.shape[0]
    cost = cost / len(dataset)
    return cost
```

And this is the code to start data training

```
while True :
    train_cost = loop_fn("train", train_set, trainloader, model, criterion, optimizer,device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        test_cost  = loop_fn("test", test_set, testloader, model, criterion, optimizer,device)
        
    callback.log(train_cost, test_cost)
    
    callback.save_checkpoint()
    
    callback.cost_runtime_plotting()
   
    
    if callback.early_stopping(model, monitor="test_cost"):
        callback.plot_cost()
        break
```

Can anyone help me with the R2 loss function ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the comments and tillmo's solution below.

Here is an implemention,

```
"""
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination
"""
def r2_loss(output, target):
    target_mean = torch.mean(target)
    ss_tot = torch.sum((target - target_mean) ** 2)
    ss_res = torch.sum((target - output) ** 2)
    r2 = 1 - ss_res / ss_tot
    return r2
```

You can use it as below,

```
loss = r2_loss(output, target)
loss.backward()
```

Comment: This would give you the R2 value, when using an optimising (e.g. Adam) it will try to minimise it, that is not what we want in this case, right? We want to train the model that would give r2 as close to 1 as possible.

Comment: Yes @Jonathan I suspect that too, so how should the optimizer be built if we want to use this r2 loss function?

Comment: @FawwazYusran the optimizers can be configured to maximize with a parameter of same name https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Adam.html

Comment: For two-dimensional tensors, you need to add `dim=0` to the calls of `torch.mean` and `torch.sum`, and aggregate the results (e.g. using the mean). Otherwise, in many cases, you will get scores better than the R2 score, leaving you with the illusion that you have learned more than you actually did.

Answer (score 1):

The following library function already implements the comments I have made on Melike's solution:

```
from torchmetrics.functional import r2_score
loss = r2_score(output, target)
loss.backward()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the maximum value of `r2_score` is 1, the output of `r2_score` should be subtracted by 1.

```
from torchmetrics.functional import r2_score
loss = 1 - r2_score(predictions, answers)
loss.backward()
```